# Tab visibility (access) to more than one profile at the same time

Tags: tab, visibility, access

I have created a new tab and I want to provide the tab visibility (access) to more than one profile:
System Administrator

Standard User

Read Only

Marketing User

Identity User

etc.. etc..

The general process I know is to go to individual profile and provide tab visibility (access).

Is there any way I can do it from a single place (instead of visiting individual profile and provide tab visibility).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is only possible upon creation. After you create a new tab, the second screen opens. Here you can choose for which profiles the tab is hidden, default off or default on. I don't think there is another way to configure a tab for multiple profiles.

Here, there is an idea that is asking what you want: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000HUNfAAO